# isset($_GET['variable']) - doesn't catch empty field

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a page on which users fill out a form to register their team:

```
<html>
<form name="newteam" method="get" action="regnewteam.php?team_name=$team_name&member1=$member1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Register Team Name:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="team_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $team_name;?>">
      <?php settype($team_name, 'string');?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Member N1:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="member1" type="text" value="<?php echo $member1;?>">
      <?php settype($member1, 'string');?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register">
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>

</html>
```

Once they submit it I check if the two fields are full in regnewteam.php using `if (isset($_GET['team_name']) && isset($_GET['member1']))`, but when the fields are empty it still executes the code in the if statement.
Why is it doing this?

Comment: It will do, empty text boxes are still passed through in the HTTP header (except `textarea`, `radio` and `checkbox` fields) ... you should use `!empty()` instead of `isset()`

Comment: *"And once they submit it I check if the two fields are full using if (isset($_GET['team_name']) && isset($_GET['member1'])),"* and where is that implemented in your code? It's not shown. Plus, what is your posted code's filename, regnewteam.php?

Comment: Just a point: The querystring here on your form tag `action="regnewteam.php?team_name=$team_name&member1=$member1"` will be doing nothing as when the form initially loads you presumably dont actually know what is going to be entered. Change it to `action="regnewteam.php"` to avoid any confusion

Comment: *We're all bubble blowers Smokey* - @RiggsFolly Can we all take a magic carpet ride?

Comment: Thank you for your participation.

Comment: Alakazam. And with a puff of _smokey_ There you go Ralph, borrow my carpet anytime @Fred-ii-

Comment: I don't understand how this is a duplicate of the other question. He never mentioned notices of undefined variables or indexes. He's saying that empty variables are passing `isset` (which they will if set).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `empty()` instead of `isset()` - empty will check if variable is empty and set at the same time.

Comment: `!empty()` rather than `empty()` but otherwise yeah ;)

Comment: Yes you are right in this particular example from @Oliver we should use `!empty()`

Comment: Thing is, this doesn't solve the immediate issue, of the undefined variables in their form's input values; they'll still get undefined variables notices. OP stated *"Once they submit it I check if the two fields are full using if (isset($_GET['team_name']) && isset($_GET['member1']))"* - which isn't shown in their question and I for one, deem the question as unclear. Personally, I would do it another way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you entire contribution to the answer on this page, has just been criticism, which isn't very helpful either ;)

Comment: @Oliver that's the thanks I get? *censored* - Your question's a duplicate and doesn't make any sense as RIggs pointed out too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry man, I got my answer so I am happy

Comment: @Oliver yeah, figured as much. *classic*

Answer (score 2):

`isset()` just checks if is it set, it could be anything not null,where as `empty()` checks if the variable is set and if it is it checks it for null, "", 0, etc. Changing

```
isset($_GET['variable'])
```

to

```
if(!empty($_GET['variable']))
```

will be a better test in the way you're trying to check this.

Comment: If at first you dont succeed Try, Try Try again. **Give some explanation or all you answers go straight to the low quality queue, and we all get to vote on them**

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. @Chandu I am tempted to start flagging your responses so that a moderator can examine your history of "try this" answers. Answers so low quality that you should be banned from answering for a while.

Comment: sorry, but you've been asked too many times about your *"Try this"* opening line. We're obviously blowing bubbles here, *aren't we Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Sure are Ralph* Time to start flagging @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Now that's much better Sam* - @JayBlanchard - good edit and the way answers should be, scrapping *"Try this"*. Let's only hope that it rubbed off on him now.

Comment: Read the edits carefully @Chandu and strive to do this in any answer that you give.

Comment: sure - @JayBlanchard, i try change my answers.

Comment: "Do or do not, there is no try." - *Yoda*

Comment: sorry, no try again.

Comment: Yoda doesn't deal with exceptions then :| @JayBlanchard

Comment: Humph, *that* never occurred to me @CD001

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers suggest using `!empty`, this will return `false` if the variable is the string (or integer) `0` which might not be what you want. An alternative is:

```
isset($_GET['variable']) && '' !== $_GET['variable']
```

Comment: `(int) 0` qualifies as empty (as it's falsey)... but yeah, I see your point with `(string) "0"` and since it's a GET var...